# Where do I start my front-end design & development with node.js?

Tags: node.js

So I have been playing around with node js for about two weeks and loving it. I am able to access my oracle instance and pull all the data that I would like to display on a webpage, preferably in a list type widget. But I do not even know where to begin!!! I watched some videos and I see some people using backbone, angular or mustache.

I just want to find something that I can use that is friendly with express and would allow widgets, pretty much just designing the form and worry about the functionality later if that is possible?

Comment: I don't really get the question. You want a CMS with nodejs in backend ?

Comment: You don't get the question yet there are answer with constructive feed back and you vote down?????

Comment: I don't vote down when I ask precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With front-end frameworks, you're best served accessing data via JSON, either by AJAX calls or by serving them up on page load.

If you want to learn about using them, I'd highly suggest starting by going through a Backbone or Angular tutorial to learn how things should be done.

This is my favorite introduction to Backbone
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrXX_CaUx7Q

Comment: I am able to serve up my data in json, but it is the json to the webpage really I would consider it the presentation layer.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. Yeah, the front-end can be considered the "presentation layer", since that is what users see.

Comment: I am going to watch that video first that you posted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to write an entire application in Node, it wasn't really designed for that and therefore lacks many features.  A popular design pattern right now is to use Node as your web server and then use a front-end framework such as Backbone, Knockout, Ember or Angular for your application.  Additionally, many people are developing these as Single Page Applications (SPA) where all navigation is handled by a router within the framework.  For DB access and general business layer tasks, you can expose functionality as RESTful API's.  You can write those API's in whatever platform you're comfortable with, but you can even write them in Javascript for a full JS-stack, top to bottom.

Regarding your question *"pretty much just designing the form and worry about the functionality later if that is possible?"*

Yes, this is possible.  When you move to a MV* pattern, delegating business layer to RESTful API's, it's possible to do a complete front-end development process even before the back-end API's are complete.  Since the interface between the front-end and back-end in this scenario would simply be RESTful API's that use JSON for data transport, it's easy to mock up API's with static (or even semi-dynamic) JSON responses.

One pattern for doing this would be to create a facade which acts as a proxy between your front-end and back-end.  The front-end calls the facade and the facade calls the back-end, etc.  You could easily have a switch in the facade which would allow to either use production API's when they are ready, or mock API's which return static values.

Comment: I can see this app as a single page app. I was messing around with jade. So just so I understand straight java script on the server with node. Jade to create my html and backbone to communicate between the server and the client?

Comment: Another reason why i am a bit lost is that i did a tutorial with just node jade and that was it. The tutorial allowed me to connect to a Mongo db and allowed for CRUD.

Comment: Well, I'll tell you our current stack but it's just one way to skin the cat.  We use Node for session management, as a proxy to back-end API's (more on that later), and to serve up just **ONE** html page, which is the page which loads our RequireJS configuration.  That config loads all our modules, jQuery + plugins, etc. and then it starts up the Marionette app, which is a plugin for Backbone.  That Marionette app is an SPA.  The html served up by Node/Jade is completely empty except for the <script> tag to load the RequireJS config file.

Comment: Yep, like I said, you _can_ write an entire app in Node but it wouldn't be an SPA.  Personally, I find that the dedicated MV* frameworks like Backbone or Angular are far more polished so that's my personal preference but it's far from the only way to do things.